# Can i delete the drive which contain microsoft and EFI named folder with FAT32 partition type

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, efi

I have one partition which can be accessed through windows explorer which contains Microsoft and EFI folder

[image: This is an image of the partition in explorer]

I am now confused that can I delete the partition and  I can't delete it from the windows partition manager. I have another partition also which is labelled as system and active

[image: Like this]

Comment: For anyone to accurately answer this, please add the output of `DiskPart`  → `Lis Vol` in a code box within your question. If that EFI partition is the only one, you cannot delete it, but if it's a secondary EFI partition, it's safe to delete only after verifying which EFI partition is actively being used, usually done via `DiskPart`.  If you're using EFI boot, the EFI partition should not be listed as `System, Active` in Disk Management _(it should be listed as `EFI System Partition`)_ - that's usually the details of a BIOS MBR boot partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [EFI system partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) (ESP). ***You must not delete it*** or your system will no longer boot, requiring boot repairs. Luckily, Windows prevents you from modifying this partition if everything is working correctly.

Usually the ESP is not assigned a drive letter on Windows. How it got one on your system, who knows. First, you should try rebooting.

Then, you may also try `mountvol e: /d` from Command Prompt or PowerShell, both as Admin and without.

Lastly, you can also try with `diskpart`, though I’ve never seen that work.

1. Run `diskpart` (it’s a command-line tool)
2. Use `list volume` to find the FAT32 ESP, you need the number
3. Use `select volume X` where `X` is the number you found
4. Use `remove letter=e`

There’s also the possibility of using the registry, but we won’t look at that unless absolutely necessary.